# C++ Problem with Pointers in subclass objects

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I have a class `touchButton` in a separate header files below. This is as i need to create an object of Adafruit's RA8875 display in my main file, as i also need it there. Thats no problem, works out fine with the pointers like this. See example below.

**touchButton.h**

```cpp
#ifndef TOUCHBUTTON_H
#define TOUCHBUTTON_H
#include "Adafruit_RA8875.h"

// Class for a touch button
class Button {
  protected:
    Adafruit_RA8875* tft;
    uint16_t *tx;
    uint16_t *ty;
    uint16_t width, height, radius;
    uint16_t x, y, color;
  public:
    // set Button values (x, y, width, height, radius, color)
    void setButton(Adafruit_RA8875* tft, uint16_t* tx, uint16_t* ty, uint16_t _x, uint16_t _y, uint16_t _width, uint16_t _height, uint16_t _radius, uint16_t _color); 

    // prints button with corresponding values of setButton function
    void printButton();

};

#endif
```

**touchButton.cpp**

```cpp
#include "touchButton.h"
#include "GENERAL.h"

// set Button  (x, y, width, height, radius, color)
void Button::setButton(Adafruit_RA8875* tft, uint16_t* tx, uint16_t* ty,uint16_t _x, uint16_t _y, uint16_t _width, uint16_t _height, uint16_t _radius, uint16_t _color) {
  this->tft = tft;
  this->tx = tx;
  this->ty = ty;
  x = _x;
  y = _y;
  width = _width;
  height = _height;
  radius = _radius;
  color = _color;
}

// prints button with corresponding values of setButton function
void Button::printButton(){
  tft->graphicsMode();
  tft->drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, radius, color);
}
```

**example for main file:**

```cpp
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_RA8875.h"
#include "GENERAL.h"
#include "touchButton.h"

// touch coordinates
uint16_t tx, ty;

// 800x480 TFT DISPLAY
Adafruit_RA8875 tft = Adafruit_RA8875(RA8875_CS, RA8875_RESET);

Button channel[18];
Button sceneLoad[6];

class Scenes {
  public:
  int number;             // numer of scene and buttons
  int textCoordinate_x;   // x coordinate of load button (for displaying some text)
  int textCoordinate_y;   // y coordinate of load button (for displaying some text)

 Scenes(int numberA, int x, int y){
    number = numberA;
    textCoordinate_x = x;
    textCoordinate_y = y;  
 }

 void printSceneBlock(){
   tft.graphicsMode();
   sceneLoad[number].printButton();
 }

};

scene[2] = {Scenes(0,25,150), Scenes(1, 165,150)}; 

void setup(){
 // set Button 
 channel[0].setButton(&tft,&tx,&ty,20,100,760,40,5, RA8875_WHITE);
}

void loop() {

 channel[0].printButton();
 scene[0].printSceneBlock();

}
```

But when using in the `scenes` class, my program crashes. This is only when i use the `scene.printSceneBlock()` function.

Before i changed this code in the separate header files, i used `tft` and `tx` and `ty` and passed it via reference in each function in the main file. this worked great, but used these passes in each function in the main file. now i changed the code so i just need to pass `tft` etc. in the `.setButton` function. As im not so experienced with pointers I'm not finding any answer that i understand. Would be much appreciated if somebody could help me explain what the problem here is. I am really stuck with this...

Comment: Can you use a debugger to find out just *where* it crashes, and more as to why?

Comment: You sure you want all those pointers? Usually a pointer to a `uint16_t`, or any other integer, is more trouble and cost than it's worth.

Comment: is there then a better option to implement a class like touchButton without these pointers? because it needs to interact with the `tft` object

Comment: This is kind of architectural. Who has need-to-know about `tx` and `ty`? Why can't `Button` store the actual values and if anyone else needs to know where the button is, they can ask the button?

Comment: Side note: try to avoid global variables. They make it real easy to write the code, but they make it pain to prove the code's correct and fix it when it is not correct. Global variables can be altered by everything in the program at any time, and this means when you're debugging, every function you call can have unintended side effects and you have to inspect everything. When you pass variables around or restrict them on a need-to-know basis you have a much smaller search area.

Comment: Plus globals make you vulnerable to weird stuff like the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)